# CSRF token is invalid after download symfony

Tags: php, symfony

When I install symfony for a new project, I got this error AT installation page (when you configure your database):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj5cH.png) - (I cant attach image cause I dont have enough reputation)

I just downloaded the repo to my machine, configured vhost, restart apache and got this. I didnt code nothing.

I know about to disable CSRF protection at config.yml

```
framework:
    csrf_protection: ~
```

But I dont want to do this. This happen to all my new project that I start when I download from symfony git repo. I even tried to change permission from dir, but nops!

Thanks!

Comment: Just do the configuration manually in the `parameters.yml` file, even better if you install symfony using composer

Comment: @tttony actually was from composer: php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition path/ 2.4.4

Comment: I tried filled parameters.yml manually but nop..